# CMAKE: how to set the compiler flags that contains a given destination path and file name

Tags: cmake, build, cross-compiling, armcc

I am working on a CMAKE build system that cross compile ARM CortexM4 using Keil ARMCC toolset in Windows

I set the c compiler flags as the following

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "-c --c99 --cpu=Cortex-M4.fp.sp --apcs=interwork --split_sections")
```

However, ARMCC compiler has options that requires to input a destination path and a file name. For instance, for each c source file, besides the object file output, I need to also output the source browser information and source dependence by adding the compiler options with the follow format:

```
--omf_browse=my_output_path/the_current_source_file.crf and --depend my_output_path/the_current_source_file.d
```

How can i add the above options to the CMAKE_C_FLAGS?

thanks

Comment: Look at https://github.com/vpetrigo/arm-cmake-toolchains

Comment: gcc compiler doesn't have options that requires to input a file name or path. as you can see from the example, the gcc compiler flags simply set as "-g3 -Og -Wall -pedantic -DDEBUG"

Comment: Basically, This is question is equivalent to "how to set the compiler flags for one input source file that produce multiple output files"

In armcc compiler, besides the object output file the  --omf_browse and --depend options also output browse information file and depend file, but the syntax requires to give a file name followed by the options. 

It's similar to visual studio c++ compiler pdb file, The CMAKE already have built-in mechanism to automatically give a name (which is the same as the source file name which different suffix). I wonder how to do the same in armcc compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple method is to set the property [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) for each needed source file.

Here is the test CMakeLists.txt

```
project(TestSourceProp)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    main.c
    file.c
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

foreach(SRC_ IN LISTS SOURCE_FILES)
    get_filename_component(SRC_BASENAME_ ${SRC_} NAME_WE)
    set_source_files_properties(${SRC_} PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "--omf_browse=${SRC_BASENAME_}.crf;--depend=${SRC_BASENAME_}.d")
    get_source_file_property(SRC_PROP_ ${SRC_} COMPILE_OPTIONS)
    message(STATUS "${SRC_}: ${SRC_PROP_}")
endforeach()
```

The output:

```
...
-- main.c: --omf_browse=main.crf;--depend=main.d
-- file.c: --omf_browse=file.crf;--depend=file.d
-- Configuring done
```

Makefile:

```
CMakeFiles/TestSourceProp.dir/main.c.obj: ../main.c
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color ...
    gcc $(C_DEFINES) $(C_INCLUDES) $(C_FLAGS) --omf_browse=main.crf --depend=main.d -o CMakeFiles/TestSourceProp.dir/main.c.obj -c ...
```

Another way, I think, is to create a custom [CMake-toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) file.

Comment: Thanks @Dmirty, That's was feasible workaround, not so elegant but doable. I don't know why CMAKE make it so difficult while other build systems such as Scons, Make can easily do this.

Comment: For more complex projects one might want to iterate over all source files of a certain target (that might not be available in a single variable). This can be done via `get_property(all_the_sources TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY SOURCES)
foreach(src ${all_the_sources}) ...`. Also, one might want to append to `COMPILE_OPTIONS` rather than just setting it.